# Samsung Galaxy Ace GT-S5830 neither goes into Download Mode nor RAM Dump Mode

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace, reboot, boot, unbricking

My Samsung Galaxy Ace GT-S5830 has just “hung” during the start-up screen with the white text “Samsung www.samsung.com" on a black background.

I have tried to restart it and to take the battery out / put it in again but the result is the same. It neither goes into Download Mode (<kbd>vol down</kbd>+<kbd>menu</kbd>+<kbd>power button</kbd>) nor RAM Dump Mode (<kbd>vol up</kbd>+<kbd>power button</kbd>).

Does anyone have any suggestions or advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Plug it into your computer and see if by some offshoot chance you have adb available.  If so, run a `adb -d reboot-bootloader` to reboot into download mode.

If that's unavailable, you are SOL and will have to have Samsung repair it.  Honestly, if it's hard bricked, you're better off buying a new phone...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say this, but if it will not go into Download Mode then your only hope would be to take into a service centre to get it repaired.

They would most likely charge you if you're rooted or have a custom ROM installed. Apologies for the bad news!

Comment: Done that buddy..they asked me to change the mother board of da phone.Thanx

Comment: @Max. Then what are you asking here for? Get them to change it :)

Comment: Thy say it will tak a month

Comment: I thought I must have an option to boot up my phone through Eclipse DDMS but I cant find any option there either!

Answer (score 0):

I found [a post on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1488715) that suggests you have to hold Home + Power till the device starts and shows the Samsung symbol, then let go. Holding it till "Samsung" appears is very important! This worked for my Galaxy Ace GT5830.